# How to join two table with customize column?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two table.

- Table A with 4 columns (Category,Product_X,Price,Color),
- Table B with 4 columns (Category,Product_Y,Price,Weight).

I want to select all data from two tables and customize columns as follow (change name column `Product_X` and `Product_Y` to `Product`, add two column `Color` and `Weight`,.etc..).

Please see image

[image]

I think i should use `JOIN`, but I still have no idea about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
    Category,
    Product_X AS Product,
    Price,
    Color,
    NULL AS Weight
FROM TableA

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Category,
    Product_Y,
    Price,
    NULL,
    Weight
FROM TableB
```